# CMD, connect to SFTP with cmd command and copy file from there

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sftp, ssh2-sftp

I know how to use "pushd" to connect to local network driver. But some of the clients files are on sftp servers.

I would like to simplify some of the jobs, but could not fine a way how to connect to clent sftp.

I red about WinSCP, could not understand the way it's works. ( as "open" command is not recognesed in cmd.)

Comment: Correct.  Open is not a valid Windows command that cmd.exe can process. But OPEN is a valid command for the third party program WinSCP.

Comment: Basically I would like to connect to sftp server copy file and paste it to local folder. Any way of doing this?